# Get uploaded image path in wordpress by filename

Tags: images

Can we get uploaded image path in wordpress by filename?
Actually I know the way in PHP that will parse all files in the **uploads** folder, and matches the each file. But that way will produce high load on server, whenever I will run this script.

Is there any other possible way?

Thanks.

Note: I do not have any posts linked with it. I just have image file name. By that only I need to find the full image uploaded path e.g. http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/test.png

Comment: You want to find a particular image by its path?

Comment: yes exactly. I just have image file name, and I want to find it's exact path ion wordpress uploads.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: how were these images uploaded?

Comment: via custom code, I just add images to server via wordpress function media_sideload_image and using same post ID-1

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you want but...

WordPress treats attached media like a custom post type. The file name, minus the extension, is stored as the `post_title` in the `$wpdb->posts` table. So, to get the path just search for the file name minus the extension.

```
$q = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'name'=>'1011722_472449312832633_575764530_n',
    'post_type' =>'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  )
);
$attid = $q->posts[0];
```

You can use `$attid` plus [`get_attached_file`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) or [`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) or other attachment function to the other information you want.

Comment: sorry dude, that is not my requirement. I only have the image name to find. There is no post ID associated with it.

Comment: If you have uploaded to the media library this is the way to do it, or at least a way. There is a post ID whether you are aware of it or not

Comment: I just add images to server via wordpress function media_sideload_image and using same post ID-1

Comment: Then you may have sidestepped everything that might help you. I'd have to check.

Comment: You could use either the post title or the slug, but be aware that the field "post_title" in the database must be referred to as "title" and the slug ("post_name" field) as "name" when you use get_posts, so the code above needs to be corrected !!!

Comment: Updated as per @ChristerFernstrom's point.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help you. I am not writing in detail as I am not sure if it was the actual question.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}
//selected file to upload
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['attachdoc'];

//wp_handle_upload to upload the file. Check documentation.
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {
   //uploaded file url
   $attachments = $movefile['url'];
   //uploaded file path
   $attachments = $movefile['file'];
}
```